# jQuery to re-enable form after a file result is returned

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC form that returns a report as a File(...) result.  This means that the browser stays on the current page after the file download is triggered.  Using jQuery, I would like to disable the submit button ***and then re-enable it after the file returns***.
My code already disables the button just fine, however, I'm unable to find an event to hook into that is triggered after the file returns.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#downloadForm").submit(function() {
            $("#cmdSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#uiProgress").show();
        });
    });
```

What can I add to this to trigger when the form submit returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to complicate the process: rather than returning the File from the post, have #downloadForm post an AJAX request that returns the URL to the file.  When the response is received, you can reenable your button and set document.location to the returned URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which works very good for me!

[Detecting the File Download Dialog In the Browser](http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/)

Answer (score 2):

I had to implement this type of feature myself recently and found this question and the link to Jesse Taber's blog very helpful, so I thought I would share my implementation here using ASP.NET MVC.

The basic theory is that you pass a token to the controller when you submit the form, and the controller sets a cookie with that value in the response when the download happens.

(Apologies for the VB.NET)

Add a property to your model to store the token:

```
Public Property DownloadToken As String
```

Then set the cookie in the response before you return the result:

```
If Response.Cookies("MyFileDownloadToken") Is Nothing Then
    Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("MyFileDownloadToken", ParameterModel.DownloadToken)

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
Else
    Response.Cookies("MyFileDownloadToken").Value = ParameterModel.DownloadToken
End If
```

Add the token property as a hidden field on your form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.DownloadToken)
```

Then we can use JavaScript to control the sumbit button and jQuery Cookie plugin to get and set the value of cookies.

```
var fileDownloadChecker;

$(function ()
{
    $("#MyForm").submit(function ()
    {
        $(".validation-summary-errors").empty(); //Clear any validation errors from a previous failed form submission
        PreventResubmission();
    });

    $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", false);
}

function PreventResubmission()
{
    //Use the current time as a unique token that we can check for in the response
    var token = new Date().getTime();

    //Set the token so that it is passed through to the controller
    $("#DownloadToken").val(token);

    //Prevent the user from resubmitting the form
    $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#submitButton").val("Running...");

    //Check once a second for the token in the response
    fileDownloadChecker = window.setInterval(function ()
    {
        var cookieValue = $.cookie("MyFileDownloadToken");

        if (cookieValue == token)
        {
            EnableFormSubmission();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function EnableFormSubmission()
{
    //Stop checking for the token
    window.clearInterval(fileDownloadChecker);
    fileDownloadChecker = 0;

    //Clear the hidden field
    $("#DownloadToken").val("");

    //Clear the cookie that contains the token
    $.cookie("MyFileDownloadToken", null, { path: "/" });

    //Enable the form submit button
    $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#submitButton").val("Run");
}
```

Things to note:

1) The default path settings for the HttpCookie class and the jQuery Cookie interface are different. By default the HttpCookie is created at root ('/'), whereas the jQuery plugin will search (and set) cookies based on current path. If reading a cookie, it will then fallback and look at other paths. So we specify the path at least when clearing the cookie. (Got into a situation where the code would work once but fail subsequently because it would find the cookie in the current path and always return that value)

2) I've added a line to enable the submit button when the page loads, because if the page refreshed for whatever reason during the running phase it would persist the "disabled" state of the button.

3) If your page is anything like mine, it displays the model validation errors BUT the page will never get refreshed upon a successful submit, so any previous validation errors will still be displayed on the form. I added a line to the submit event handler of the form to clear any child elements from any element with the class ".validation-summary-errors".

Comment: This idea worked really well, thanks. Only thing I want to add is I had to add         `cookie.HttpOnly = false;`  when creating the cookie on controller, so it would be readable client side.